# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } when using JQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting the above error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }) when I am using Jquery Flot and cannot work out what is causing it.

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">

function gd(year, month, day) 
    {
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
    }

$(function() {
    var d1 = [<?php echo $javastring; ?>];
     $.plot($('#rankings'), [d1], {
         label: "Disk 1",
          data: d1,
          legend: { show: true
                },
        grid: {hoverable: true, clickable:true},
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d/%m",
            minTickSize: [1, "day"]
            },
        yaxis: {
            transform: function (v) { return -v; },  
            inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; },
            min:1, 
            tickDecimals: 0,
            tickSize: <?php echo $track; ?>
        },
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true });
});

function formSubmit(formid)
    {
    document.getElementById(formid).submit();
    }
                        </script>
```

This is then used for a graph to be created as below;

```
<div id="rankings"  class="center" style="height:300px; width:600px;"
></div>
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem, the other javascript function that is at the bottom just submits forms with the onclick function.

Any ideas/help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a javascript syntax error

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing curly brace between `points: { show: true }` and `);`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is right, it should be `points: { show: true }});`

Comment: New code still shows the same error.
        `points: { show: true }});`